# Laravel cName SSL Certificates

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I’m developing a SaaS application with the Laravel framework. For each single application the user can choose a Subdomain to access the dashboard. For example myapp.example.com

Now I’ve integrated a cName function to allow my users white label dashboards. I use the default Laravel domain router.

My question is how to handle SSL certificates for the cName domains. The application general runs over ssl. So when a cName is created, I need a cert for this domain. My idea was to generate a free let’s encrypt ssl for these domains. But so I have to add each cert to nginx. I think that’s not the best idea because it will be very unstructured and I need a additional solution to sync the configuration between many servers.

How would you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate for the whole application.
https://medium.com/@saurabh6790/generate-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-273e432794d7

Comment: Yea sure. I’m already use a wildcard for my domain. But the user can link their own domain to the dashboard. So I can’t creat a cert for their domains

Comment: Hmm, you will probably need your clients to point their domains to your NS, which means that you will need to run your own NS. Or maybe this could be done with CNAME.